# I keep getting segmentation faults. How is a stack used in IA-32 using AT&T?

Tags: assembly, att, x86

For a homework assignment, we have been asked to scan a number, increment it by one and print the answer. However, code tends to give a segmentation error.

```
.global main

mystring: .asciz "Assignment 3: inout\n"

string: .asciz "%d"

main:   pushl $mystring
        call printf
        jmp inout

end:    pushl $0
        call exit
```

This is basically what we're doing. Running a code like this without the jump works. The problem is in the inout method

```
inout:  subl $0, %esp             ;what is happening here
        leal -4(%ebp), %eax       ;what am i doing here
        pushl %ebp                ;why do i need to push the base pointer
        movl %esp, %ebp
        pushl %eax
        pushl $string
        call scanf
        incl %eax
        pushl %eax
        pushl $string
        call printf
```

Which doesn't seem to work. I also have no idea what the beginning (substract, address thing) means, see the commentary for further things. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer, but maybe this will help you track down the problem:

`subl $0, %esp` *would* grow the stack if the constant wasn't zero. The top of the stack is usually at the lowest memory address in x86, that is, stacks grow downwards.

`leal -4(%ebp), %eax` loads the absolute address `%ebp - 4` into `%eax`. This is the pointer to the memory location where the `scanf`d integer should be stored.

Why you're `push`ing the base pointer is indeed a relevant question. You usually do that because you modify it afterwards, do stuff, and then `pop` it when you're done - which it seems you don't. It is usually used with functions that you `call` though. This might well be the problem here, you call `inout` a method, but you're using it as a label for `jmp` only. The code as you have posted it now has no chance of returning to where it was `jmp`ed to from.

[Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames) has a fairly concise introduction to x86 stack frames.

Comment: In addition, `scanf` returns the number of items read in `%eax`, not the number `scanf`ed. Incrementing `%eax` isn't going to give the result you're looking for.